# Implementing search functionality in spring and HQL

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hql

I am implementing search in my spring boot app. Search term is searching through first name, last name and email. In my database I store name in two columns: first name and last name. What I want to achieve is to let the user type in the full name (first name + last name) and search the database. I tried this, but when all parameters are empty this query returns me empty set, and I expected it to return all users.

```
   @Query("FROM Employee e WHERE "
            + "lower(concat(e.firstName,' ',e.lastName)) like lower('%'+':fullName'+'%') AND "
            + "lower(e.email) like lower('%'+':email'+'%')")
    public Page<Employee> search(@Param(value = "fullName") String fullName,
                                 @Param(value = "email") String email,
                                                         Pageable page);
```

I am not sure if I can use `concat` like this. If that is a problem is there an alternative?

**Edit**

I've tried removing `%` signs from query and it worked. It seems I just have to place them right, but I don't know how.

This worked:

```
@Query("FROM Employee e WHERE "
            + "lower(concat(e.firstName,' ',e.lastName)) like lower(:fullName) AND "
            + "lower(e.email) like lower(:email)")
    public Page<Employee> search(@Param(value = "fullName") String fullName,
                                 @Param(value = "email") String email,
                                                         Pageable page);
```

The question is only how to use `%`.

Comment: untested, but if you remove the single quotes from `'e.firstName'` and `'e.lastName'` you should be fine as HQL supports `concat`

Comment: @msparer Tried it, still nothing..

Comment: @msparer Another problem was I was putting quotes on parameter names (':email'), now I got question marks instead of them in log, which is correct. I've just tried that without '%' signs, and it worked. I just have to place '%' correctly it seems. I've edited question, so if you have a guess let me know. Thanks.

Comment: "+", as I remember, is allowed inside where clauses only when doing arithmetic operations. My guess is that your HQL query string `'%' + ':email' ...`  is valid (Hibernate accepts it) but probably does not do anything quiete understandable. I would try to rewrite as `mail like concat('%', lower(:email), '%')`. Or, more probably, deal with the '%' from the java side before htting the HQL query.

Comment: @GPI Thanks a lot, that was it. Post an answer if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably that HQL interprets this part of the query in a way that does not suit your need :

```
lower(e.email) like lower('%'+':email'+'%')")
```

From the [HQL specification](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/jboss_enterprise_application_platform/5/html/hibernate_core_reference_guide/queryhql-expressions), I know that the "+" sign is allowed as an arithmetic operator, but I'm not sure it is allowed in any other use.

Obviously, your statement "means something", as Hibernate does not report it as a syntax error, but I'm at a loss to know what it does mean, seeing we are not in an arithmetic context. Maybe it concatenates the string but does not replace the placeholder ? It would be interesting to have Hibernate activate the showSQL and log it, or to see the compiled version of the query object to introspect it, but I have no time to do that right now.

Anyway, in order to achieve the same result, in a predictable way, I suggest you rewrite to

```
mail like concat('%', lower(:email), '%')
```

which I find non ambiguous.